# Pandas compare rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about comparing rows in dataframe. Sorry if someone already asked that question, I can't find a solution to it.
For example, I have such a Dataframe:

```
     A     B     C    Group_id
1    A-1   B-1   C-1     1
2    NaN   B-2   C-2    NaN
3    A-2   B-2   C-2     2
4    A-3   B-4   C-4     3
```

How I can compare all rows that have **group_id** as **Nan** **AND** **A** as **NaN**
with all other rows by **B** and **C** columns and set **group_id** if there is such matches
So my result should look like this:

```
     A     B     C    Group_id
1    A-1   B-1   C-1     1
2    NaN   B-2   C-2     Nan -> 2   ## as row 3 has the same C and C
3    A-2   B-2   C-2     2
4    A-3   B-4   C-4     3
```

Thanks, everyone for helping. A lot!

Answer (score 0):

First filter out rows with missing values in `Group_id` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), so possible use left join by original DataFrame with replace `NaN`s by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
L = ['B','C']
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Group_id']).drop_duplicates(L)

df['Group_id'] = df['Group_id'].fillna(df[L].merge(df1, how='left', on=L)['Group_id'])
print (df)
     A    B    C  Group_id
1  A-1  B-1  C-1       1.0
2  NaN  B-2  C-2       2.0
3  A-2  B-2  C-2       2.0
4  A-3  B-4  C-4       3.0
```

Or you can check membership by `MultiIndex` values from `B/C` columns:

```
mask = df['Group_id'].isna()

L = ['B','C']
df1 = df[~mask].drop_duplicates(L)
print (df1)
     A    B    C  Group_id
1  A-1  B-1  C-1       1.0
3  A-2  B-2  C-2       2.0
4  A-3  B-4  C-4       3.0

s = df1.set_index(L)['Group_id']
df.loc[mask, 'Group_id'] = df[mask].set_index(L).index.map(s)
print (df)
     A    B    C  Group_id
1  A-1  B-1  C-1       1.0
2  NaN  B-2  C-2       2.0
3  A-2  B-2  C-2       2.0
4  A-3  B-4  C-4       3.0
```